# Kill buffers in *Buffer List* by file path

Tags: kill-buffer, buffer-list

I have **a lot** of buffers in `*Buffer List*`.

```
    a.hs      1708 Haskell          ~/src/my-project/src/a.hs
    b.hs       581 Haskell          ~/src/my-project/src/b.hs
    c.hs      1711 Haskell          ~/src/other-project/tests/c.hs
    d.hs       687 Haskell          ~/src/random-project/d.hs
```

Is there a convenient way to mark rows (maybe similarly to `Dired`) using patterns or regex? The intention is to mark/kill all buffers that refer to files in `my-project`.

Comment: Have you tried `M-x ibuffer`? Quote the doc:  ( ‘% f’ - Mark buffers by their filename, using a regexp. )

Comment: +1 for `ibuffer`. I have rebound `C-x C-b` to `ibuffer` and have been using it exclusively for some years now. In the `ibuffer` buffer, you can do `?` for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I join others in recommending Ibuffer, which is similar to the classic buffer list (Buffer Menu mode) but has a lot more features. (That's if you're not using something even fancier like Ido or Helm.) `M-x ibuffer` opens the buffer list in the current window, like `M-x buffer-menu`. `M-x ibuffer-other-window` opens the buffer list in another window (like the default `C-x C-b`) and (unlike `C-x C-b`) selects it.

Ibuffer has many commands that are similar to [Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html). You can use `d` to flag the current item for deletion and `x` to actually delete all items flagged for deletion. You can use `m` to put a mark on the current item and `D` to delete the items that are marked (with a confirmation prompt). There are also features to mark buffers based on their properties, but they're slightly different from Dired's. In Ibuffer, use `% f` to mark buffers by their file name (that's the full path including directories). So you can delete `my-project` buffers with

```
% f ~/src/my-project/ RET D y
```

Another possible approach which works both in the classic `C-x C-b` Buffer Menu and in Ibuffer is to sort the buffer list by names. You can then quickly flag consecutive items for deletion. In the classic buffer list, use `S` (`M-x tabulated-list-sort`) while the cursor is at the beginning of a file name (the lines are sorted based on what's to the right of the cursor). In IBuffer, use `s f` to sort by file name (and `s v` to go back to the default sort by recency).

Comment: This is a very thorough answer, thank you.